# How can I deploy an iOS app for enterprise distribution?

Tags: ios, enterprise

I want to distribute an iOS app for enterprise deployment. I have experience with app distribution through the App Store, but this is my first time with enterprise distribution, and I have a few questions.

1. According to document, it mentions MDM. Do I need to use a specific solution for MDM, or is it possible to use a simple web server (such as express.js) for distribution?
2. If I upload an iOS enterprise app, can anyone download it? If not, it needs to authorize that user belongs organization for download app?

Comment: It is much easier to distribute enterprise apps via an MDM product.  If you don't use an MDM and distribute via a web server, the enterprise agreement with Apple requires that the app is on a secured web site that requires the user to authenticate with company credentials before they are able to download the app. In general, Apple recommends you use a custom app via App Store Connect rather than enterprise distribution, if possible. Using an MDM is still the best approach with custom apps.